# What does the CSS `not` selector do?

Tags: css

I saw the following snippet in a css file.  What does it do?

```
h3 ~ *:not(h3) {
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

Obviously it alters `h3` headers in some way but I don't understand what `~ *:not(h3)` does.

Googling `~ *:not(h3)` is unproductive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The isn't HTML. It is a [CSS selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/).

Specifically, it is the [negation pseudo-class](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#negation):

> The negation pseudo-class, :not(X), is a functional notation taking a simple selector (excluding the negation pseudo-class itself) as an argument. It represents an element that is not represented by its argument.

---

> Obviously it alters h3 headers

No, it does exactly the opposite. It stops the selector from matching h3 elements.

Comment: Terrific answer.  Thank you for taking the time to explain and correct my understanding.

Answer (score 2):

This is CSS, not HTML.  See [Mozilla's documentation on the CSS negation pseudo class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not) for more details, but `not` basically selects elements that do *not* match the specified selector (in this case, `h3`).